# What's difference between those two std::vector's assign methods?

Tags: c++, vector, assign

There are two ways (that I know) of assigning one vector to another:

```
std::vector<std:string> vectorOne, vectorTwo;
// fill vectorOne with strings

// First assign method
vectorTwo = vectorOne;

// Second assign method
vectorTwo.assign( vectorOne.begin(), vectorOne.end() );
```

Is there really difference within those methods or they are equal in terms of efficiency and safety when performed on very big vectors?

Comment: Equal, the first probably calls the second in any case, or they both call some common underlying routine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're pretty much equivalent.  The reason for the second is
that you might have types which need (implicit) conversion:

```
std::vector<int> vi;
std::vector<double> vd;
//  ...
vd.assign( vi.begin(), vi.end() );
```

Or the type of the container might be different:

```
vd.assign( std::istream_iterator<double>( file ),
           std::istream_iterator<double>() );
```

If you know that both of the containers are the same type, just
use assignment.  It has the advantage of only using a single
reference to the source, and possibly allowing move semantics in
C++11.

Comment: Or you only want to assign from a sub-range of the source.

Comment: +1 And note that `.assign(beg,end)` requires the arbitrary type `T` be emplace-constructible or move-insertible (the latter for `std::vector<T>` specifically when the iterator type does not meet forward iterator requirements). The requirements for the assignment operator are different; `T` must be copy-insertible and copy-assignable. Not that it matters much in the OP's case, but just to note that they're not always as near-equivalent. They certainly are in this case.

Comment: Are there any guaranteed that `assign` will do only one allocation when passed random access iterators?  (ie, are we guaranteed that optimization)

Answer (score 7):

The second form is generic, it works with any iterator types, and just copies the elements from the source vector.

The first form only works with exactly the same type of `vector`, it copies the elements and in C++11 might also replace the allocator by copying the allocator from the source vector.

In your example the types are identical, and use `std::allocator` which is stateless, so there is no difference. You should use the first form because it's simpler and easier to read.

Comment: The point about the allocator is a good one: the first does copy the allocator, the second does not.  (Not an issue with the default allocators, but it could be with other allocators.)

Comment: And the point about the allocator is not new to C++11.  It has been present since C++98.

Comment: @JamesKanze Are you sure? C++03 specifically says ([lib.container.requirements]/8) that the allocator provided at construction is used for all allocation for the container's lifetime, and (a copy of) that same allocator is returned by `get_allocator()`. C++11 has similar wording but adds _"or until the allocator is replaced. The allocator may
be replaced only via assignment or `swap()`."_

Comment: I think that's a bug fix in the standard.  I can't believe that the committee changed the intended behavior in this regard.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was a very intentional change. `allocator_traits<A>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment` defaults to false, so there is no change in behaviour for any C++03 allocators, only new C++11 allocators which expressly request the change can be replaced by assignment. In C++03 there was no protocol for an allocator to say it should be replaced on assignment, so containers could not know if replacing it was safe or desirable, so never replaced the allocator.

Comment: It was intentional to specify allocators more precisely; the original standard was very vague about them, and different implementations did different things with them.  But I don't know what they actually did in `operator=`, nor what the standard intended.  (As part of the "observable state", one might expect that they be transferred on assignment.  But `capacity` is also part of the observable state, and it is clear that it may be different between the target and source after assignment.)

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent in this case. [and C++03 standaerd]. The difference will be however if vectorTwo contains elements before assignment. Then

```
vectorTwo = vectorOne; // use operator=
// Any elements held in the container before the call 
// are either assigned to or destroyed.

vectorTwo.assign() // any elements held in the container
// before the call are destroyed and replaced by newly 
// constructed elements (no assignments of elements take place).
```

`assign` is needed because `operator=` takes single right-hand operand so `assign` is used when there is a need for a default argument value or range of values. What `assign` does could be done indirectly by first creating **suitable** vector and then assigning that:

```
void f(vector<Book>& v, list<Book>& l){
    vector<Book> vt = (l.begin(), l.end());
    v = vt;
}
```

however this can be both ugly and inefficient (example has been taken from Bjarne Stroustrup "The C++...")

Also note that if vector is not of the same type then there is also need for `assign` which allows implicit conversion:

```
vector<int> vi;
vector<double> vd;
//  ...
vd.assign( vi.begin(), vi.end() );
```

Comment: The `.assign(b,e)` form is also allowed to assign to existing elements (at least in C++11.)